# Managing error report popups

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, html5

I recently started learning jQuery and JavaScript and put this together for the site I work on [here](http://wncba.co.uk/results).

```
/*
 * Manages the error report popups
 *
 * written by Tom Jenkinson
 */


jQuery(document).ready(function($) {


    var bottomTableReport = {

        timer: null,

        init: function() {
            this.mouseover();
            this.mouseout();
        },

        mouseover: function() {
            var self = this;
            $(".report-error").mouseover(function() {

                if(typeof(this.timer) != 'undefined')
                {
                    clearTimeout(this.timer);
                }
                $(this).find('.text').css('display','inherit');

            });
        },

        mouseout: function() {
            var self = this;
            $(".report-error").mouseout(function() {

                var self2 = this;
                this.timer=setTimeout(function() {

                    $(self2).find('.text').css('display','none');

                },300);

            });

        }
    };

    bottomTableReport.init();







    function initialiseProblemQtips()
    {

        var htmlBottomTable= new Array();
        htmlBottomTable[0] ='<div class="error-report-popup-1">';
        htmlBottomTable[0]+='<div class="main-content">';
        htmlBottomTable[0]+='<span class="text-1">Please click on the <img src="images/icons/error.png" /> next to the information in the table that is incorrect.</span>';
        htmlBottomTable[0]+='<span class="text-2">If the error doesn\'t have the symbol next to it please <a class="link">click here</a>.</span>';
        htmlBottomTable[0]+='</div>';
        htmlBottomTable[0]+='</div>';

        htmlBottomTable[1] ='<div class="error-report-popup-1">';
        htmlBottomTable[1]+='<div class="main-content-2">';
        htmlBottomTable[1]+='<span class="title">Report An Error</span>';
        htmlBottomTable[1]+='<span class="text-1">To report an error with this table please click on the e-mail address below to send a message to the manager.</span>';
        htmlBottomTable[1]+='<span class="email">&rarr; <a class="link" href="mailto:'+errorReportEmail+'?subject=Website Table Error">'+errorReportEmail+'</a> &larr;</span>';
        htmlBottomTable[1]+='</div>';
        htmlBottomTable[1]+='</div>';

        var htmlTable='<div class="error-report-popup-2">';
        htmlTable+='<div class="main-content">';
        htmlTable+='<span class="title">Report An Error</span>';
        htmlTable+='<div class="error-id">';
        htmlTable+='<span class="text">Error id: </span><span class="code"><img src="images/icons/code_loading.gif" alt="Loading"></span>';
        htmlTable+='</div>';
        htmlTable+='<span class="text-1">To report an error with this part of the table please click on the e-mail address below to send a message to the manager.</span>';
        htmlTable+='<span class="text-2">Please make sure that the error id above is quoted in your message.</span>';
        htmlTable+='<span class="email">&rarr; <a class="link" onclick="alert(\'Please wait for the error id to be retrieved first.\');return false;" href="">'+errorReportEmail+'</a> &larr;</span>';
        htmlTable+='</div>';
        htmlTable+='</div>';

        $(".report-error-container").css('display', 'block');

        var popupVisible = new Object();

        $(".report-error, .report-error-table").qtip(
        {
            content: '', //set later in api
            position:
            {
                target: false, //it is changed in the 'beforeRender' part in api section
                corner:
                {
                    target: 'bottomMiddle',
                    tooltip: 'topRight'
                }
            },
            show:
            {
                when:
                {
                    event: 'click'    
                },
                delay: 0
            },
            style:
            { 
                name: 'cream',
                tip:
                {
                    corner: 'topRight'
                },
                padding: 0,
                width: 400,
                border:
                {
                    radius: 5,
                    width: 0
                }
            },
            hide:
            {
                when:
                {
                    event: 'unfocus'
                }
            },
            api:
            {
                beforeRender: function() {

                    this.targetThis = $(this.elements.target);
                    this.options.position.target = $(this.targetThis).find('.icon');
                    this.elements.target = this.options.position.target; //update this as well. I don't actually know what it's use is

                    var tableNo= $(this.targetThis).attr('data-tableNo');

                    if($(this.targetThis).hasClass('report-error'))
                    {
                        this.options.position.adjust.screen = false;
                    }
                    else if($(this.targetThis).hasClass('report-error-table'))
                    {
                        this.options.position.adjust.screen = true;
                    }
                },

                onRender: function () {

                    this.qtipThis=$("div[qtip='"+this.id+"']");
                },

                beforeShow: function () {

                    var tableNo= $(this.targetThis).attr('data-tableNo');

                    if($(this.targetThis).hasClass('report-error'))
                    {
                        this.updateContent(htmlBottomTable[0],true);
                    }
                    else if($(this.targetThis).hasClass('report-error-table'))
                    {
                        this.updateContent(htmlTable,true);
                    }

                },

                onShow: function() {

                    var tableNo= $(this.targetThis).attr('data-tableNo');
                    popupVisible[this.id] = true; //creates item in array or updates it
                    showHideIcons(tableNo);
                    this.updatePosition(false,false);
                    if($(this.targetThis).hasClass('report-error'))
                    {
                        var self=this;
                        $(this.qtipThis).find(".link").click(function () {

                            self.updateContent(htmlBottomTable[1],true);

                        })
                    }
                    else if($(this.targetThis).hasClass('report-error-table'))
                    {
                       var self = this;
                       $.post("ajax_requests.php?action=get_error_code", {data:$(this.targetThis).attr('data-errorData')}, function(data) {

                           $(self.qtipThis).find('.code').html(data);

                           $(self.qtipThis).find('.email .link').attr('onclick', '');
                           $(self.qtipThis).find('.email .link').attr('href', 'mailto:'+errorReportEmail+'?subject=Website Table Error (Error id: '+data+')');

                       });

                    }
                },

                onHide: function() {

                    var tableNo= $(this.targetThis).attr('data-tableNo');

                    popupVisible[this.id] = false;
                    showHideIcons(tableNo);

                }
            }
        });

        var iconTimer = new Object();
        function showHideIcons(tableNo)
        {
            action = 'h';
            for (x in popupVisible)
            {
                if (popupVisible[x]===true)
                {
                    action = 's';
                    break;
                }
            }
            if(action=='s')
            {
                if(typeof(iconTimer[tableNo]) != 'undefined')
                {
                    clearTimeout(iconTimer[tableNo]);
                }
                $('.report-error-table-icon[data-tableNo='+tableNo+']').css('display','inline-block');
                $('.report-error-table-icon-inline[data-tableNo='+tableNo+']').css('display','inline');
            }
            else if(action=='h')
            {
                iconTimer[tableNo]=setTimeout(function() {

                    $('.report-error-table-icon[data-tableNo='+tableNo+']').css('display','none');
                    $('.report-error-table-icon-inline[data-tableNo='+tableNo+']').css('display','none');
                }, 2500);         
            }
        }
    }


    initialiseProblemQtips();



});
```

The script location is [here](http://www.wncba.co.uk/results/javascript/error-reportingv2.js). You can see it working by clicking on an exclamation mark under a table.

Is there a better way of doing this or are there any improvements that could be made to it?

Comment: `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Comment: @ThiefMaster I've seen that the current best-practice is to avoid `= new array()`, but can you provide some detail as to why `[]` is preferable?

Comment: Looks better and when creating a single-element array `[5]` works while `new Array(5)` would create an array containing 5 `undefined` elements.

Comment: also in that bit where I put the html into the variable is there a way of wrapping it across lines (like in php) so I don't have to append to the variable for each line?

Comment: @ThiefMaster Indeed! Are there any other improvements? I admit that it's also cleaner when creating arrays through loops (which a great many are) since you don't need to allocate an empty array just to fill it.

Comment: @TomJenkinson use a backslash \ in the end of the line, and it wraps to the next. (ES5 feature, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/8090192/148412 )

Comment: @ANeves That is recommended against [by Google](http://google-styleguide.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javascriptguide.xml?showone=Multiline_string_literals#Multiline_string_literals). Besides, then you're mixing your code indentation into the data it's dealing with.

Comment: the string concatenation example on that page is pretty much what I was looking for.

Comment: @st-boost thank you, I misunderstood what he meant. To continue a statement in the next line one can leave a hanging operand at the end of the sentence, like a +. To have linebreaks inside strings one can use `line 1\nline 2` or a backslash at the end of the line and continue on the next.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### `[]` instead of `new Array()`

Initialize arrays with `[]` instead of `new Array()` - it looks better, and when creating a single-element array [5] works while new Array(5) would create an array containing 5 undefined elements;

### Long strings in multiple lines, rather than concat

Do

```
var str = "The quick brown fox" +
        " jumped over the lazy dog.";
```

instead of

```
var str = "The quick brown fox";
str += " jumped over the lazy dog."
```

### `===` instead of `==`

Use `===` instead of `==`, and `!==` instead of `!=`. `==` **is not transitive**:

```
'' == 0; // true
0 == "0"; // true
'' == "0"; // false!
```

### Avoid using inline styles

Ideally JS would be used to add or remove classes, and those classes styled through CSS.

Separate responsibilities.

### Pick names carefully

```
var htmlBottomTable= [];
```

Its name should be pluralized, since it holds a *set* of things.

```
bottomTableReport.mouseover
```

I would use a more suggesting name: `bottomTableReport.setMouseover`.

### Reuse `$('foo')` when possible

Instead of repeatingly getting `$(".report-error")`, you can store it once and reuse it:

```
var bottomTableReport = {
    timer: null,
    target: $(".report-error"),
    // ...
    mouseover: function() {
        // ...
        this.target.mouseover(function() { // Reusing.
        // ...
```

Comment: +1 all a very valid points that should be considered. The inline styles would have to be my favorite, separating the logic from the design.